# Listing completed processes in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

I have a PID,but the process is not running anymore and has completed. I need to get the complete details associated with that PID.
Is it possible?
I am using Solaris 5.1 OS.

Comment: If the PID is no longer in existence, then there are no details to get. So, in a sense, you already have the complete details associated with that (and every other non-existent) PID... Oh, and Solaris 5.1? Really? I'm sorry...

Comment: If you're talking about a zombie process, you can probably start from ps(1); if the process has been wait(2)ed, there's probably nothing you can do.

Comment: @twalberg Don't pids get recycled in solaris 5.1?

Comment: @TheJoker Yes - in fact PIDs get recycled in pretty much every Unix/Linux I've ever seen. Otherwise, you'd need to reboot every couple of hours on busy systems (although you'd have a little extra time on idle systems). But once a particular process finishes, that PID will, for some period of time until it is re-used, be non-existent.

Comment: @twalberg Then this question isn't right don't you think, Because the info about the given pid might be about a completely new process(if the old process has finished execution ofcourse!)

Comment: @TheJoker Ok, obvious sarcasm failure, I guess. You're right that getting the info on a completely new process that happens to get the same PID is a possibility. My point was, on the other hand, about the fact that, as long as the PID doesn't exist (hasn't been re-used yet), there is no information to be had, so everyone in the world already has all the information there exists on that PID (i.e. none)... Twisted logic, I know, but logically correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process is a zombie, then you can find it by

> ps -ef |grep -i defunct

Otherwise(if the process isn't a zombie) there is no way to retrive the information